# What phase-noise can I expect for high-end microwave sources?

Tags: microwave

I would like to know what type of phase-noise I can expect if I want to be able to produce a single RF frequency source.

It does not have to be tunable, it just needs to be around 10 GHz. What is the state-of-the-art for electronics that can do such a stable microwave source?

I have found one [here](https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/20298/rf-microwave-signal-generator-covers-100-khz-to-50-ghz), but would like have more detailed information about the sideband noise. (Perhaps a table for dBc/Hz for 10GHz for different frequencies.)

Comment: First you need a data sheet from the manufacturer. Then for us, are you a user, or are you wanting to design your own source? State of the art differs in each frequency offset range. The very lowest system phase noise will be a PLL combining the best of XOs and DROs, at different offsets. PhDs have been written, companies formed and built, designing good phase noise sources. The implmentation will be somewhat different for fixed frequency and wide tuning range sources.